# How can I get output value from the stored procedure in C# using Entity Framework

Tags: c#

I have connected a stored procedure to a C# program using Entity Framework with a `.edmx` model. I am trying to get an integer output value to a variable from the stored procedure which was connected to entity. How can I get the output result from the stored procedure to the local variable?

Here is the code in C#

```
_db = new DbEntities();
int id = 0;
var fleetid = _db.GetNextFleetId(id);
```

SQL Server stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE dbo.GetNextFleetId 
    @NewId bigint OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT @NewId = NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.seqFleets;
    RETURN;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we add stored procedure to edmx model from the database.

we can try to use [ObjectParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.objects.objectparameter?view=netframework-4.8) to get output value from stored procedure.

```
ObjectParameter outPutId = new ObjectParameter("NewId", typeof(long));
_db.GetNextFleetId(outPutId);

//output value
Convert.ToInt64(outPutId.Value);
```

Comment: When I given the above code  it shows the error  no overload method GetNextFleetId takes 1 argument in  the line _db.GetNextFleetId(outPutId);

Comment: Have you imported stored procedures from your 
edmx model or tried to refresh that? because your  sp might need to input a parameter https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/stored-procedure-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: I am getting null value to the variable outPutId